# The Prisoner's Release Probability Problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The release of two out of three prisoners
has been announced. but their identity is kept secret. One of the prisoners considers
asking a friendly guard to tell him who is the prisoner other than himself that will be
released, but hesitates based on the following rationale: at the prisoner's present state
of knowledge, the probability of being released is $\frac{2}{3}$, but after he knows the answer,
the probability of being released will become $\frac{1}{2}$, since there will be two prisoners
(including himself) whose fate is unknown and exactly one of the two will be released.
What is wrong with this line of reasoning?

Comment: This sounds like a Monty Hall variant.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of this prisoner being released is already $0$ or $1$.  The prisoner has no agency in determining who is or is not released.